# replace only one variable in web.py templates

Tags: python, templates, web.py

I am passing variable to template in web.py and have the same condition in some places. Like this:

$if myvar=="string1":

```
$passed argument1
```

............

$if myvar =="striung2":

```
$passed argument2
```

If say myvar is "string1" and I pass passed = "AAA" then   I have AAA argument1 on my page, but the other if statements get replaced by empty string?

How to avoid that? I.e. how to leave other statements intact?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  What are you trying to do?  It sounds like you just need to use else:

```
if myvar == "string1":
  print passed
else:
  # something
```

But it's very hard to understand what you are asking.